# Wireless Connectivity and Fedora 15 Boot Up

Tags: fedora, wifi

I'm currently running Fedora 15 and recently I've noticed that if I am in an area which does not have a wireless network or a secured wireless network which I cannot automatically connect to, Fedora 15 boots up very slowly, sometimes hanging on the screen with the Fedora logo. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hey man do you have multiple accounts here that you need to merge or are there just a rash of new users that like numbers in the 80 thousands?

Comment: If you can get it to boot, post the output of `systemctl --full` when booting without network access.  If you can't, add `systemd.log_target=kmsg` to your kernel command line and remove `rhgb quiet` and post the last few lines of output where it hangs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably happens due to DNS, and the machine (or individual services) are waiting onbeing able to resolve hostnmaes during the boot process. The most likely culprit is actually your own machine's hostname. To avoid this problem, make sure you have your machine's hostname listed in `/etc/hosts` like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost hostname
```